# How do I Link a TD in dataTable?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, datatables

I have a function like this. How do I hyperlink specific columns? Lets say I want to have the Download FIle render like this Download File And where uploadFile/file is the path of my download link. When I try to run this function, it not fill the table. Could you guys help me out?

```
function tabela() {

    var table = $("#example1").DataTable({
            "ajax": "pages/forms/request.php",
            "columns":

                [
                    { "data": "ID" },
                    { "data": "SERIAL_NUMBER" },
                    { "data": "AUDITOR" },
                    { "data": "FALHA" },
                    {
                        "data": "ARQUIVO",
                        "fnCreatedCell": function(nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                            $(nTd).html("<a href='uploadFiles/" + oData.ARQUIVO + "'>Download File</a>");
                        },
                        { "data": "DATA" },
                    ]

                }
        );
    }
    tabela();
```

Comment: Are you working with the "datatables" plugin?

Comment: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/58324

Comment: Yes, I'm.. Pick up the dataTable lib

Comment: Have you read the post I linked?

Comment: It works Perfectly, thanks a lot!